# Performance Issue with JavaFX multiple tabs simultaneous updates of TextArea

Tags: javafx

I'm relatively new to JavaFX and have written a small applet which launches a number of (typically between 3 and 10) sub-processes. Each process has a dedicated tab displaying current status and a large TextArea where the process output is appended to. For simplicity all tabs are generated on startup.

```
javafx.application.Platform.runLater(() -> logTextArea.appendText(line)))
```

The applet works fine when workloads on sub-processes are low-moderate (not many logs), but starts to freeze when sub-processes are heavily used and generate a decent amount of logging output (a good few hundreds of lines per second in total).

I looked into binding the TextArea to the output, but my understanding is it effectively calls the `Platform.runLater()` method so there will still be hundreds of calls to JavaFX application thread per second.

Batching logging outputs isn't an ideal solution either because I'd like to keep the displayed log as real-time as possible.

The only solution which I think might solve the problem seems to be dynamic loading of individual tabs. This would definitely prevent unnecessary calls to update logging textareas that aren't currently visible, but before I go ahead to make the changes, I'd like to get some helpful advice from you here. Thanks!

Comment: There are a couple of possibilities for why this is slowing things down. One is the number of calls to `Platform.runLater(...)`. You can "throttle" the number of calls if that is an issue (e.g. create a buffer for the text - if the buffer is not empty schedule a `Platform.runLater()`, and append to the buffer in any case. In the `Platform.runLater()` get all the text from the buffer and clear it. You need to carefully synchronize access to the buffer.)

Comment: The other possibility is simply that you have too much string concatenation going on. Ultimately, the text area holds all the text as a single entity. In that case, the solution might be to use a different UI component, such as a `ListView`, which can more efficiently manage the volume of data.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the reply. Do you think the updating of background tabs is a major concern? I know ideally I should use something like VisualVM to profile it and see the cost of each function call, but I'd like to get some quick ideas from here first.

Comment: I doubt the background tabs make much difference. If a handful of these processes are slowing the app, it's likely just one on its own could, under the right conditions. So that suggests you need to improve the underlying strategy somehow.

Comment: If each line of text is not dependent on the other, try using a `ListView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions. Finally got around to implementing a fix today.

The issue was fixed by using a buffer coupled with a secondary check for time lapse (maximum 20 lines or 100 ms).

In addition, I also implemented rolling output to limit the total process output to 1,000 lines.

Thanks again for your invaluable contribution!